# combining multiple dataframe within loop in r

Tags: r, data-binding, loops

Here is just small example (not exactly, but similar issue) I am trying to do:

```
test1 <- data.frame (matrix(sample( c(1,2,3,NA),15, replace = TRUE), 5,3))
 X1 X2 X3
1 NA NA  2
2  1  3  3
3 NA  1 NA
4 NA  2 NA
5  2 NA  3
```

I want loop the process with 5 different seeds with 1:chr. I want to then combine the resulting dataframe in column wise:

```
X1  X2  X3 X1.1 X2.1 X3.1  ... so on (r will accept two variables with same name) 

 X1 X2 X3  X1 X2 X3 X1 X2 X3 X1 X2 X3 X1 X2 X3
1 NA NA  2 1 NA NA  2 1 NA NA  2 1 NA NA  2
2  1  3  3 2  1  3  3 2  1  3  3 2  1  3  3
3 NA  1 NA 3 NA  1 NA 3 NA  1 NA  3 NA  1 NA 
4 NA  2 NA 3 NA  1 NA 3 NA  1 NA 3 NA  1 NA 
5  2 NA  33 NA  1 NA 3 NA  1 NA 3 NA  1 NA
```

Here is my trial:

```
nchr = 1:5
seed <- round(runif(nchr)*1000000)

funct <- function (x){
set.seed <- seed[x]
test1 <- data.frame (matrix(sample( c(1,2,3,NA),15, replace = TRUE), 5,3))
return (test1)
}

sapply(nchr, funct)
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> do.call(cbind, lapply(nchr, funct) )
  X1 X2 X3 X1 X2 X3 X1 X2 X3 X1 X2 X3 X1 X2 X3
1 NA  1  2  2  2  1  2  1  2  3  1 NA NA  1  3
2  1  1  3 NA NA NA  3  2 NA  3  1  1  3  2  1
3  3  3  2  2  2  3  2  2  3  1  1  1  2 NA  2
4  1  2  1  2  1  1 NA  2  3  1  2  1  2  2 NA
5  2  2  1  1  1 NA  1  3  2  3 NA  3  3  2  3
```